# Pandas apply function using two columns from dataframe to create a new one

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a simple function that counts weekends and holidays within two dates in python...

count_holiday_and_weekends(fromdate,todate)

How do i apply the function to create a new one in my df ?

Something like:

df['count_holiday_and_weekends'] = count_holiday_and_weekends(df['fromdate'],df['todate])

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with parameetr `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
df['count_holiday_and_weekends'] = df.apply(lambda x: count_holiday_and_weekends(x['fromdate'],x['todate']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which columns to be used in the function you can do

```
df.assign(count_holiday_and_weekends=df[['fromdate','todate']].apply(count_holiday_and_weekends,axis=1))
```